# Find the minimum value with the same id in a list

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of objects with a structure similar to this:
Id, OperationId, Prop1, Prop2, ...

I must remove from the list all object that have the same Id but have a Max value for OperationId..
For example I have this Instance of the list:

```
new List<MyObject>
{
    new MyObject() { Id = 1, OperationId = 1, Prop1, Prop2, ... },
    new MyObject() { Id = 1, OperationId = 2, Prop1, Prop2, ... },
    new MyObject() { Id = 2, OperationId = 1, Prop1, Prop2, ... },
    new MyObject() { Id = 2, OperationId = 2, Prop1, Prop2, ... },
    new MyObject() { Id = 3, OperationId = 2, Prop1, Prop2, ... }
}
```

The result must be:

```
new List<MyObject>
{
    new MyObject() { Id = 1, OperationId = 1, Prop1, Prop2, ... },
    new MyObject() { Id = 2, OperationId = 1, Prop1, Prop2, ... },
    new MyObject() { Id = 3, OperationId = 2, Prop1, Prop2, ... }
}
```

An important thing: I don't have to find just the Id and the operationId.. the result must be the whole object!

I have tried with Comparer, lambda expression, Distinct, Grouping and Select, but I haven't find the solution...

How Can I solve?

Thanx,
Simone

Comment: What if you'll have three objects with OperationId 1, 2, 3 for same Id?

Comment: So, basically, you're looking for the result to be distinct by the Id but to be the minimum available based on operation id?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, I must take always the object with the minimum OperationId

Comment: @Clint, yes, correct.. I am looking for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
myObjects = myObjects
    .Groupby(obj => obj.Id)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(obj => obj.OperationId).First())
    .ToList();
```

That removes all duplicates according to the ID and only the lowest OperationId remains.

Comment: That's my first attempt :) What if there two items with OperationId 1, or if there three items with OpeationIds 1, 2, 3?

Comment: This will select just distinct Id for Min OperationId.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: my understanding was that the primary goal of OP is to remove duplicates, so only one object should remain. If multiple lowest OperationId are possible OP has to add `ThenBy` after the `OrderBy`. But the logic should be clear.

Comment: @TimSchmelter at first glance I thought the same

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: the question body is a little bit unclear since he's mentioning "have a Max value for OperationId". The title is clearer.

Comment: @Jack: it selects the whole objects into a `List<MyObject>`. But the final list doesn't contain duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Group objects by Id, then from each group select only objects which don't have max OperationId. But keep in mind, if there is only one OperationId value in group, you should return all these objects (minOperationId check):

```
var result = from o in objects
             group o by o.Id into g
             let maxOperationId = g.Max(o => o.OperationId)
             let minOperationId = g.Min(o => o.OperationId)
             from o in g
             where o.OperationId == minOperationId || o.OperationId != maxOperationId
             select o;
```

For input

```
{ Id = 1, OperationId = 1 }
{ Id = 1, OperationId = 2 }
{ Id = 2, OperationId = 1 }
{ Id = 2, OperationId = 2 }
{ Id = 2, OperationId = 3 }
{ Id = 3, OperationId = 1 }
{ Id = 4, OperationId = 1 }
{ Id = 4, OperationId = 1 }
```

Output will be

```
{ Id = 1, OperationId = 1 }
{ Id = 2, OperationId = 1 }
{ Id = 2, OperationId = 2 }
{ Id = 3, OperationId = 1 }
{ Id = 4, OperationId = 1 }
{ Id = 4, OperationId = 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your object is something like:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Int32 Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Int32 OperationId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}-{1}", this.Id, this.OperationId);
    }
}
```

We can use the following LINQ query:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyObject> RemoveMaxOpIdInIdGroup(List<MyObject> items)
{
    var result = items
        // Group by id
        .GroupBy(item =>
            item.Id)
        // Select each group and max operation id in each group
        .Select(group =>
            new { group, maxOperationId = group.Max(item => item.OperationId) })
        // From each group select the item where opid is not max for this 
        // group or if the group has only one item
        .SelectMany(groupWithMax =>
            groupWithMax
                .group
                .Where(item =>
                    (item.OperationId != groupWithMax.maxOperationId) ||
                    (groupWithMax.group.Count() == 1)));
    return result;
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
var items = new List<MyObject>()
{
    new MyObject() { Id = 1, OperationId = 1},
    new MyObject() { Id = 1, OperationId = 2},
    new MyObject() { Id = 2, OperationId = 1},
    new MyObject() { Id = 2, OperationId = 2},
    new MyObject() { Id = 3, OperationId = 2}
};

foreach (var obj in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
}

var result = RemoveMaxOpIdInIdGroup(items);

Console.WriteLine("Result:");
foreach (var obj in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `MaxBy` extension method, [such as the one written by Jon Skeet](https://morelinq.googlecode.com/hg/docs/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MaxBy__2.htm), the solution becomes fairly simple:

```
var result = items.GroupBy(item => item.Id).Select(x => x.MaxBy(y => y.OperationId));
```

(Note that in the case of several items with the Id and OperationId, it is arbitrary which maximum one is chosen.)

Sample program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class MyObject
    {
        public int Id;
        public int OperationId;
    }

    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            IEnumerable<MyObject> items =
                new List<MyObject>
                {
                    new MyObject{Id = 1, OperationId = 1},
                    new MyObject{Id = 1, OperationId = 2},
                    new MyObject{Id = 2, OperationId = 1},
                    new MyObject{Id = 2, OperationId = 2},
                    new MyObject{Id = 3, OperationId = 2}
                };

            var result = items.GroupBy(item => item.Id).Select(x => x.MaxBy(y => y.OperationId));
        }
    }

    public static class EnumerableMaxMinExt
    {
        public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
        {
            return source.MaxBy(selector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
        }

        public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
        {
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence was empty");
                }

                TSource max = sourceIterator.Current;
                TKey maxKey = selector(max);

                while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    TSource candidate = sourceIterator.Current;
                    TKey candidateProjected = selector(candidate);

                    if (comparer.Compare(candidateProjected, maxKey) > 0)
                    {
                        max    = candidate;
                        maxKey = candidateProjected;
                    }
                }

                return max;
            }
        }
    }
}
```